# Task Updates Databinded OC which doesn't reflect on UI

Tags: wpf, multithreading, data-binding, mvvm

I Recently started development on WPF using the MVVM Model witht he MVVM Light Toolkit.

I have a listbox in listboxView which has a listboxViewModel. In the listboxViewModel, I have an ObseverableCollection (**items**) that raises a PropertyChanged in the setter.

Databinding to the listbox was no issue.

The issue is that when I try to use a Task to asynchronously pull data from my database (online source) and update **items**, the changes does not reflect on the UI.

However, if i were to call the method without the task, causing the UI to freeze till the data reaches me, the UI reflects the changes.

The code I used in the task is as follows:

```
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                return new CCDatabase().CCDB;
            }).ContinueWith(taskState =>
            {
                items = taskState.Result;
            }, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

It just doesn't make any sense. My best guess is that it has something to do with the contexts of the task. However, when I add a breakpoint in the setter of my items, the value is correct which is 5 (5 is the number of rows i have in the table in the database).

My question is, if I want the UI to update and at the same time reap the benefits of my UI not freezing everytime I make a call to the database, how can it be done.

I am coding in VS2010 so i dont have access to the wonderful async/await magic. I am currently using the EntityFramework 6.0 for the database calls.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ContinueWith` operation you are passing `default scheduler` which will get scheduler from ThreadPool. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402.aspx) documentation -

> The default scheduler for Task Parallel Library and PLINQ uses the
>   .NET Framework ThreadPool to queue and execute work.

And since you cannot modify UI components from other thread that's why it's not getting update on UI.
Instead use `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` which will get you a scheduler for an UI thread and dispatch your operation on UI thread.

This will work -

```
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return new CCDatabase().CCDB;
        }).ContinueWith(taskState =>
        {
            items = taskState.Result;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: I actually took that into consideration and tried it out previously to no avail. The problem however was that I had 2 PropertyChanged events, one from the ViewModelBase that my ViewModel inherited and one which i explicitly defined. Removing the extra PropertyChanged Event and its corresponding method fixed the issue.

I will keep in mind your answer as it pretty much applies to the Context of the ViewModel. Running it on the TaskScheduler.Default will not work.

Comment: However, if you run the code on default scheduler, it will fail silently since UI objects can't be modified on background thread. If you put try catch around line `items = taskState.Result` you will see exception gets thrown but doesn't crash your application. But anyhow if its working for you then its fine. :)